# sqlite3 python leave a blank column

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I created a table with 8 columns, i want to just insert values less than the column number. How can I do that? An answer would be much appreciated.

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_transaction VALUES(:empID, :date, :time_in_morning, :time_out_morning, :time_in_afternoon, :time_out_afternoon,:Tardy,:Undertime)""",
                  {--here i want to insert like just the empID, time_in_morning and time_out_morning--})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just specify the columns for which you are providing data in the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tb_transaction (empID, time_in_morning, time_out_morning)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Your Python code:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_transaction (empID, time_in_morning, time_out_morning) VALUES (:empID, :time_in_morning, :time_out_morning)""")
```

The above might not work on SQLite (though it certainly works on MySQL).  One workaround you could try would be to do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, with placeholders:

```
INSERT INTO tb_transaction (empID, time_in_morning, time_out_morning)
SELECT ?, ?, ?;
```

Here is the Python code for that:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_transaction (empID, time_in_morning, time_out_morning) SELECT :empID, :time_in_morning, :time_out_morning""")
```

Comment: I've done that and it gives me an error like "OperationalError: table tb_transaction has 8 columns but 3 values were supplied"

Comment: @Sev I'm surprised this doesn't work on SQLite, despite that I know it works on other databases.  In this case, you may try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: No, it works, i just used the wrong format. Thanks for the help.